# How to localise the name of iOS Application programmatically or from plist or by any other way?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am currently working on a iPhone project,i was succeeded to localise the alert's text and the remaining all text according to the country, but the problem is, now my client wanted to see the app name based on the country, below the app icon in app menu. I don't have any idea to achieve this even

Thanks in-advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to go through good example form Reywenderlich, http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014

Go with **Gratuitous Bonus** section from tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a guide to localise app name
 http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/12/15/localize-iphone-application-name.html